# How to check versions with Json and without using DynamoDBVersion attribute?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

In our project we use JSON.NET to serialize our objects and then send them to DynamoDB:

```
public class TestClass
{
    ...
    public long Version { get; set; }
}

using (var client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonDynamoDBClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
{
    var table = Table.LoadTable(client, "MyTable", DynamoDBEntryConversion.V2);
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject((TestClass) obj);
    var item = Document.FromJson(json);
    await table.UpdateItemAsync(item);
}
```

The problem with the code above is that DynamoDB does not perform version checking on server-side using the Version property. How can I perform version checking with JSON?

```
public class TestClass
{
    // We do not pass our classes to AWS SDK, so we cannot use this attribute
    [DynamoDBVersion]
    public long Version { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are interested in [Conditional Writes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.ConditionalUpdate).  Even though you are using JSON to represent the object it is still possible to include a condition on your call to DynamoDB to update the item.  However, it requires the use of the UpdateItemSpec instead of just providing the Item directly to the Table object.

Even with the conditional write, you will only be able to fail the write if a certain condition is not met such as the version being different or the item not already existing.  You can then have separate logic deal with that edge case.  Conditional writes can be used to check that any field in the item meets any specific condition, for use use case you would apply the logic to the Version attribute.